# How to Tokenize block of text as one token in python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize

Recently I am working on a genome data set which consists of many blocks of genomes. On previous works on natural language processing, I have used `sent_tokenize` and `word_tokenize` from nltk to tokenize the sentences and words. But when I use these functions on genome data set, it is not able to tokenize the genomes correctly. The text below shows some part of the genome data set.

```
>NR_004049 1
tattattatacacaatcccggggcgttctatatagttatgtataatgtat
atttatattatttatgcctctaactggaacgtaccttgagcatatatgct
gtgacccgaaagatggtgaactatacttgatcaggttgaagtcaggggaa
accctgatggaagaccgaaacagttctgacgtgcaaatcgattgtcagaa
ttgagtataggggcgaaagaccaatcgaaccatctagtagctggttcctt
ccgaagtttccctcaggatagctggtgcattttaatattatataaaataa
tcttatctggtaaagcgaatgattagaggccttagggtcgaaacgatctt
aacctattctcaaactttaaatgggtaagaaccttaactttcttgatatg
aagttcaaggttatgatataatgtgcccagtgggccacttttggtaagca
gaactggcgctgtgggatgaaccaaacgtaatgttacggtgcccaaataa
caact
>NR_004048 1
aatgttttatataaattgcagtatgtgtcacccaaaatagcaaaccccat
aaccaaccagattattatgatacataatgcttatatgaaactaagacatt
tcgcaacatttattttaggtatataaatacatttattgaaggaattgata
tatgccagtaaaatggtgtatttttaatttctttcaataaaaacataatt
gacattatataaaaatgaattataaaactctaagcggtggatcactcggc
tcatgggtcgatgaagaacgcagcaaactgtgcgtcatcgtgtgaactgc
aggacacatgaacatcgacattttgaacgcatatcgcagtccatgctgtt
atgtactttaattaattttatagtgctgcttggactacatatggttgagg
gttgtaagactatgctaattaagttgcttataaatttttataagcatatg
gtatattattggataaatataataatttttattcataatattaaaaaata
aatgaaaaacattatctcacatttgaatgt
>NR_004047 1
atattcaggttcatcgggcttaacctctaagcagtttcacgtactgttta
actctctattcagagttcttttcaactttccctcacggtacttgtttact
atcggtctcatggttatatttagtgtttagatggagtttaccacccactt
agtgctgcactatcaagcaacactgactctttggaaacatcatctagtaa
tcattaacgttatacgggcctggcaccctctatgggtaaatggcctcatt
taagaaggacttaaatcgctaatttctcatactagaatattgacgctcca
tacactgcatctcacatttgccatatagacaaagtgacttagtgctgaac
tgtcttctttacggtcgccgctactaagaaaatccttggtagttactttt
cctcccctaattaatatgcttaaattcagggggtagtcccatatgagttg
>NR_004052 1
```

When the tokenizer of ntlk is applied on this dataset, each line of text (for example `tattattatacacaatcccggggcgttctatatagttatgtataatgtat` ) becomes one token which is not correct. and a block of sequences should be considered as one token. For example in this case contents between `>NR_004049 1`  and `>NR_004048 1` should be consider as one token:

```
>NR_004049 1
tattattatacacaatcccggggcgttctatatagttatgtataatgtat
atttatattatttatgcctctaactggaacgtaccttgagcatatatgct
gtgacccgaaagatggtgaactatacttgatcaggttgaagtcaggggaa
accctgatggaagaccgaaacagttctgacgtgcaaatcgattgtcagaa
ttgagtataggggcgaaagaccaatcgaaccatctagtagctggttcctt
ccgaagtttccctcaggatagctggtgcattttaatattatataaaataa
tcttatctggtaaagcgaatgattagaggccttagggtcgaaacgatctt
aacctattctcaaactttaaatgggtaagaaccttaactttcttgatatg
aagttcaaggttatgatataatgtgcccagtgggccacttttggtaagca
gaactggcgctgtgggatgaaccaaacgtaatgttacggtgcccaaataa
caact
>NR_004048 1
```

So each block starting with special words such as `>NR_004049 1` until the next special character should be considered as one token. The problem here is tokenizing this kind of data set and i dont have any idea how can i correctly tokenize them.
I really appreciate answers which helps me to solve this.

**Update:**
One way to solve this problem is to append al lines within each block, and then using the nltk tokenizer. for example This means that to append all lines between `>NR_004049 1` and `>NR_004048 1` to make one string from several lines, so the nltk tokenizer will consider it as one token. Can any one help me how can i append lines within each block?

Comment: try with regex?

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus I have not tried with regex. Actually i dont know how should i work with them. Is it possible for you to help me with code?

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus I really appreciate you i you help me with this problem. I really dont know what should i do and i need a help

Comment: @ i added update part. can you please help me with that?

Comment: To my knowledge it doesn't make sense to use NLP tokenizers for genetic data, NLP tokenizers are designed/trained to deal with human languages. What do you consider a correct token in this case? Also there's lot of research on genetic data, there is probably a standard method to tokenize this (maybe simply char by char).

Comment: @Erwan yes you are right. tokenizers in nltk are trained for natural language. In my case a token is a sequence of characters. for example, all genomes between ``` >NR_004049 1``` and ``` >NR_004048 1 ``` are considered as one token. If i could be able to append all lines between ``` >NR_004049 1 ``` and ``` >NR_004048 1 ``` it will solve me problem. Can you please Update part.

Comment: @Erwan To solve this problem i want to concatenate all lines between two special word such as ```>NR_004049 1``` and ```>NR_004048 1``` and ... to empower the nltk tokenizer to treat them as one token. For example, first block which consistes of 10 lines, should be concatenate to generate one line which is a long sequence of characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to concatenate the lines between two ids apparently. There should be no need for nltk or any tokenizer, just a bit of programming ;)

```
patterns = {}
with open('data', "r") as f:
    id = None
    current = ""
    for line0 in f:
        line= line0.rstrip()
        if line[0] == '>' :  # new pattern
            if len(current)>0:
#                print("adding "+id+"  "+current)
                patterns[id] = current
                current = ""
            # to find the next id:
            tokens = line.split(" ")
            id = tokens[0][1:]
        else: # continuing pattern
            current = current + line
    if len(current)>0:
        patterns[id] = current
#        print("adding "+id+"  "+current)


# do whatever with the patterns:
for id, pattern in patterns.items():
    print(f"{id}\t{pattern}")
```

Comment: I really appreciate your effort and your answer. It really solved my problem. Thank you very much sir